# Al generar un ejecutable con el módulo pkg, aparece Warning Cannot include directory %1 into executable

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, puppeteer, whatsapp-web, pkg

Estoy desarrollando un programa para mandar mensajes por whatsapp por medio del módulo whatsapp-web.js. Deseo hacer mi programa un ejecutable, para ello estoy usando "pkg", sin embargo al momento de generar el ejecutable, me sale el siguiente mensaje.

```
Warning Cannot include directory %1 into executable.
The directory must be distributed with executable as %2.
%1: ..\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium
%2: path-to-executable/puppeteer
```

Ya copié la ruta donde la pide, aquí lo pueden ver en vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al correr el ejecutable me sale esto:

```
C:\snapshot\romer\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Launcher.js:105
            throw new Error(missingText);
                  ^

Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (982053).
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (C:\snapshot\romer\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Launcher.js:105:23)
    at PuppeteerNode.launch (C:\snapshot\romer\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Puppeteer.js:125:31)
    at Client.initialize (C:\snapshot\romer\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:95:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at Function.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1941:13)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

¿Alguien sabe como resolver este error? He buscado en foros pero no he visto nada que me sirva.

Comment: ¿Versión de npm y versión de node?

Comment: C:\Users\romer>node -v
v16.14.2

C:\Users\romer>npm -v
8.7.0